# Scrollability of Android Linear Layout

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout

According to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)

> A layout that organizes its children into a single horizontal or vertical row. It creates a scrollbar if the length of the window exceeds the length of the screen.

I have a Linear Layout (vertical) that consist of a stack of TextView, EditText and one button. Reading the documentation above, I would expect that my layout will scroll by default when there is not enough space to display (e.g. when soft keyboard is on). But apparently it doesn't scroll until I wrap my Linear Layout with ScrollView.

Do I understand the documentation incorrectly? Please help me to understand this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I understand the documentation incorrectly?

It is a bug in the documentation. `LinearLayout` does not scroll on its own.

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation. A bug in documentation should be pretty easy to fix :p